# multipart form data request in alamofire in swift4?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift4, alamofire

Hello i am new to swift4 and trying to call multipart form data request by alamofire library in swift4 language? here below is my code

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append("1422".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "u_id")
            multipartFormData.append("How???".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "firstname")
            multipartFormData.append("We are woking on it!!".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "description")
        }, to: "URL_TOcall", encodingCompletion: { result in
            print("result  = \(result)")
            switch result {
            case .success(request: let request, streamingFromDisk: false, streamFileURL: nil):
                //Success code
                break

            case .failure:
                print("failed api calling")
                break


            case .success(let request, true, _):
                //Code here
                break

            case .success(let request, _, _):
                // Code here
                break
            }


        })
}
```

Comment: What is your issue ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya i am calling url and its in post method, reponse is coming correct but parameters that i am posting in mutablearraydata are not getting updated in server.

Comment: i have tried in postman and its working fine but with this function of code here its getting failed.

Comment: Your post parameter are in http body or as query string in url ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya in http body

Comment: thats why i am sending in multipartFormData here

Comment: ya correct your code looks fine to me. you are correctly passing it. May be it is issue from your server guy

Comment: but its working fine in postman so i dont think server side will be any issue

Comment: Y do you want to use multipart upload ??  Since there is no images , you can go for ordinary method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue it was too silly and small thing that i was not doing but after adding  **allowLossyConversion: false** to my string conversion just did the trick.

```
{
 //corrected indentation for code

 Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append("1422".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "u_id")
        multipartFormData.append("How???".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "firstname")
        multipartFormData.append("We are woking on it!!".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "description")
    }, to: "URL_TOcall", encodingCompletion: { result in
        print("result  = \(result)")
        switch result {
        case .success(request: let request, streamingFromDisk: false, streamFileURL: nil):
            //Success code
            break

        case .failure:
            print("failed api calling")
            break


        case .success(let request, true, _):
            //Code here
            break

        case .success(let request, _, _):
            // Code here
            break
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: But what does that mean `allowLossyConversion : false`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing issue because you have not uploaded image data

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            // MISSING THIS LINE
            if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourimage) {
                multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "", fileName: "filename\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)")
            }

            multipartFormData.append("1422".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "u_id")
            multipartFormData.append("How???".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "firstname")
            multipartFormData.append("We are woking on it!!".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "description")
    }, to: "URL_TOcall", encodingCompletion: { result in
        print("result  = \(result)")
         switch result {
            case .success(let request, _,  _):
                print(request)
                request.responseJSON(completionHandler: { (resonse) in
                    print(resonse)

                })


            case .failure( let error):
                print(error)
                break
            }
       }

    })
}
```